# Webpack lazy loading import IE 11 Promise undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading, bluebird, polyfills

I am using Webpack 2 with `import()` but in IE 11 I got error

> Dynamic page loading failed ReferenceError: 'Promise' is undefined

though I am using bluebird to polyfill `Promises` in client of my React application with `babel-preset-bluebird`

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /
    use: {
    loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
            presets: [['es2015', { modules: false }], 'react', 'stage-2', 'stage-3', 'bluebird'],
            plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'lodash']
        }
    }
}
```

how can I fix lazy loading with `import()` in IE 11?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the preset transforms all `Promise` calls, even those generated by webpack? Webpack will generate something `Promise` based for each `import()`.

Comment: Hi, so how it is possible to fix this using any polyfill for webpack?

Comment: You would have to apply some processing after webpack has done its job or polyfill separately to fix this. Now you have an ordering issue.

Comment: You mean first should be 'bluebird' preset than others?

Comment: It would not fix the issue. Webpack will still apply processing of its own even after the loader has done its job.

Comment: so how it is possible to fix?, how can I do processing after webpack job and what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137257/discussion-between-aren-hovsepyan-and-juho-vepsalainen).